# ¿Que controles basicos debo aplicar al usar un formulario conectado a base de datos?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario para registrar los usuario de mi APP. Los datos los guardo en una base de  datos MYSQL,  el formulario en la APP y el PHP para guardar los datos funcionan bien.

En el formulario de la APP hay unos filtros para evitar que ingresen caracteres no validos o que no deben ir en el campo, igualmente al cargar el formulario genero un numero aleatorio que aparece en el formulario y que el usuario debe digitar.

Aunque en la base de datos no pretendo guardar datos secretos o valiosos, existen personas inescrupulosas que dañan lo de otros, simplemente por hacer el daño, pregunto, ¿Los controles o filtros que coloque en el formulario sirven de algo o debo colocar algo mas sofisticado para evitar que hacken la base de datos, llenen de registros basura la base de datos, o dañen la base de datos?

Gracias por sus sugerencias

Parte del codigo del formulario con el que capturo los datos de los usuarios es el siguiente.

```
        <EditText
            android:hint="Nombre completo"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/ediText_nombre"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="Id"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/ediText_id"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:id="@+id/text_captcha"/>

          <EditText
              android:hint="Digite las letras que aparecen arriba"
              android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
              android:layout_width="250dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:id="@+id/ediText_captcha"
              android:digits="1234567890"
              android:maxLength="4"/>
```

El codigo java para generar el numero aleatorio de 5 numeros que el usuario debe digitar es este:

```
        String captcha;

            Random rrr = new Random();
            int Low = 10000;
            int High = 100000;
            int Result = rrr.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

            captcha = Integer.toString(Result);
            text_captcha.setText(captcha);
```